# Temporarily change a function variable in elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

**Update**

This question is no longer feasible.

Turned out `ivy-read` doesn't return immediately as I expected. I used `C-g` to cancel completion which skips the restoring `ivy-format-function` part.

---

I'm writing an ivy extension with dynamic collection. I'd like to return a list of list of strings instead of a list of strings as candidates. The default value of `ivy-format-function` only supports list of strings so I decide to change it to my own function while calling `ivy-read` then change it back.

I defined the following macro and function:

```
(defun ivy-foo ()
  (interactive)
  (with--ivy-foo-format-function
   (ivy-read "Foo: "
             #'ivy-foo-function
             :dynamic-collection t
             :require-match t
             :action #'ivy-foo--action
             :unwind #'ivy-foo--unwind
             :history 'ivy-foo-history
             :caller 'ivy-foo)))

(defmacro with--ivy-foo-format-function (&rest body)
  `(let ((original-function ivy-format-function))
     (setq ivy-format-function (lambda (candidates) (ivy-foo--format-function candidates original-function)))
     ,@body
     (setq ivy-format-function original-function)))

(defun ivy-foo--format-function (candidates original-format-function)
  (funcall original-format-function
           (mapcar
            (lambda (cand)
              (if (listp cand)
                  (car cand)
                cand))
            candidates)))

(defun ivy-foo-function (str)
  (list (list "cand1" str) (list "cand2" str)))
```

`with--ivy-foo-format-function` doesn't set `ivy-format-function` to the original value. I got error "Symbol's value as a variable is void: original-function". What's wrong?

Update: `ivy-format-function` is a `defvar`. Its default value is `#'ivy--format-function-default`

Comment: At least put a comma in front of `original-function`, in the `lambda`. And why are you using a macro at all? Have you tried advising `ivy-format-function` or using `flet`?

Comment: Thanks.

More details: `ivy-format-function` is a `defvar` with default value to `#'ivy--format-function-default`.

Putting comma only makes it worse. I chose macro because I don't want body be evaluated eagerly.

How does `flet` work here? I need to reference the original function.

Haven't learnt advising yet :(

Comment: Is there anything to perform by a macro which can't be realized with a function? A function is much easier to debug. When done, write it as a macro again maybe.

Comment: @AndreasRöhler Thanks I figured out the problem. As of macro vs function, I'm new to elisp and don't know if I can lazily evaluate `body` without using a macro.